# How to delete an imageview through code in xcode

Tags: xcode, imageview, cgrect

My goal is to delete an imageview when it reaches the side of the screen. It is supposed to be a bullet and when its x value reaches a certain value it gets deleted. 
Here is the code for the sensor but once it reaches 120 I want it to be deleted:

```
CGRect frame = Image.frame;
if (frame.origin.x>120) {
   NSLog(@"delete");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the imageview do this.

```
[myImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

(where `myImageView` is the name of your imageview)

Comment: Never give a variable a name that starts with a capital letter. And don't call it `image` when it is an image view (UIImageView), since there is another class, UIImage. A good name for your example variable would be `myImageView`.

Comment: He sets his CGRect from Image.frame, so I assumed that is what he wanted to delete, and yes instance variables should not start with capital letters class names should. etc etc